# File writing in java

Tags: java

I've just started on my college journey ( 'Yay' ). I'm also new to the site so feel free to lecture me on things I may have done wrong as far as asking questions is concerned.

I was given a project, which has already been graded and all, and the program should ==>> ***first read lines of standard input (Input file name using keyboard) and for each line of input, if the user enters exit, the application terminates; otherwise, the application interprets the line as a name of a text file. The application creates or recreates this file and writes to it two lines of output, the name of the file and the current date and time. The application then closes the file, reopens it for reading, and writes its contents to standard output. The application writes to standard output the name of the file enclosed by square brackets. After writing the file name, 
the application writes the contents of the file with each line prefixed by its corresponding line 
number, a full colon, and a space.***
I have worded it just as my professor did, so I apologize for any unclear statements. Here's what I got for it:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project1
{
  public static void main() throws IOException
  {       
    String input = "";
    while(!sc.equals("exit"))
    {
        System.out.println("Enter file here!\n Type 'exit' to terminate");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        input = sc.nextLine();        
        try
        {
            File file = new File (input,".txt"); // Creates pointer to a file.
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            file.createNewFile();
            file.getAbsolutePath();
            printFileAndDate(file);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.print("Something wrong :(");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  System.exit(0);
  }
  static void printFileAndDate(File temp)
  {   
     DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
     Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
     System.out.println("[ " + temp.getPath() + " ]");
     System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
  }        
}
```

What I attempted to do there was the following:

-Get User Input => Save Input as a file => Call method "printFileAndDate" and print the file along with the current date and time in the correct format.

However, whenever I run it, it always gives me an exception error, which means the file was never really created or that it isn't able to find it.

Comment: can you post up the stack trace? post up your exception errors?

Comment: Always show the exact error in the question.

Comment: this is asking for a `code review`, see http://codereview.stackexchange.com for that in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***The list of ISSUEs, I could find :***

**First**, your main method signature is totally wrong

```
public static void main() throws IOException
```

change to

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
```

**Second**, it is not a good practice to throws exception inside main method.

The good practice is to use try catch block

**Third**, you have your Scanner varialbe after the while loop which does not make sense

```
 while(!sc.equals("exit"))
         {
        System.out.println("Enter file here!\n Type 'exit' to terminate");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); <-?!!!!!!
```

change to

```
   System.out.println("Enter file here!\n Type 'exit' to terminate");
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
   while(!sc.equals("exit"))
         {
```

**Fourth** , you define File variable this way

```
 File file = new File (input,".txt"); <-- totally wrong
```

change to

```
File file = new File ("input.txt"); <-- if you use relative path
```

**Fifth** there is not need for `System.exit(0);`at the end of `main` method

Comment: Fifth, no need for `System.exit(0)` at the end of `main`.

Comment: @DavidConrad I agree why vote down?

Comment: I didn't down vote you.

Comment: down voters explanation is appreciated :)

Comment: @DavidConrad I don't  get why voted down the perfect explanation :)

Comment: Well, I'll give you +1. It's a good answer. If I had to guess, maybe the downvoter doesn't like an answer on a closed (dup) question, but I don't see the problem. Maybe the downvoter will comment.

Comment: @DavidConrad I totally appreciate your support, but I answered this before being closed. If it is closed there is no way, I could post up my answer. Down voting is ok if they explain why? so I can rectify my issue and be better